# Next.js server side api call returns 500 internal server error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm finally dipping my toe into the world of server side react using [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/), however I'm pretty stumped with this issue.

I'm making a call to an API from `pages/customer-preferences.tsx` using `isomorphic-unfetch`

```
CustomerPreferencesPage.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(API_URL + '/preference-customer');
  const initialData = await res.json();
  return { initialData };
};
```

All works fine locally in `dev` mode or once built and ran `build` > `start`. To host it I'm running it from a docker container `node:10`, and when I run this locally all is fine also. The issue only happens once it's deployed.

When I navigate to `/` and then click a link to `/customer-preferences` all works as expected. But if I refresh the page or load the page directly at `/customer-preferences` I see this error from Next.js

[image]

So the issue only seems to happen when trying to make the API calls from the server and not the client.

I've also setup a simple express server to use instead, but not sure if this is necessary?!

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  server.all('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  server.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

When checking the server logs I get this:

```
FetchError: request to http://xxx failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN xxx xxx:80
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this provide any help to you? https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/15780#issuecomment-425930255

Comment: @MichalisGarganourakis yeah saw that, but no responses on that thread either

Comment: @xadm I'm needing a hybrid app. That's for completely static apps

Comment: don't use absolute URL, use  relative URL  that will solve your problem

Comment: @divyang4481 the API is not relative to the app though

Answer (score 1):

No, the server setup is not necessary.

This is happening because the browser/client is not capable of resolving your docker container's hostname. As it stands, the only solution I know of is to check for the req object in `getInitialProps` (so as to determine which environment the fetch will run in) and call the Docker hostname when on server, localhost when on client. E.g.

```
async getInitialProps (ctx) {
    if (ctx.req) // ctx.req exists server-side only
    {
        // call docker-host:port
    }
    else {
        // call localhost:port
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My suspicion has to do with the fact that `fetch` is not a native node module but a client in browsers. So, if you navigate from one page to this page; per the documentation; getInitialProps will be called from the client side, making the `fetch` method accessible. A refresh ensures that the getInitialProps called from the server side.

You can test this theory by running `typeof fetch` from a browser's inspector and from a node REPL.

You are better of calling the method from component or using a third-party HTTP client like `axios`...

If you want to skip calling the AJAX method from the backend and only call it from the frontend, you can test if the method is calling from the frontend or the backend, like so:

```
CustomerPreferencesPage.getInitialProps = async () => {
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    // this is being called from the backend, no need to show anything
    return { initialData: null };
  }

  const res = await fetch(API_URL + '/preference-customer');
  const initialData = await res.json();
  return { initialData };
};
```

Comment: `I'm making a call to an API from pages/customer-preferences.tsx using isomorphic-unfetch`

Comment: @cr05s19xx Not quite. Isomorphism *is* the culprit here, but this has nothing to do with the module import. The issue is that `getInitialProps` is isomorphic and therefore calls the Docker hostname on the client AND the server. The hostname is exposed as localhost on the client-side.